# Selected Radio Buttons Error

Tags: c#

I am developing a project that generates questions from a database, the questions are generated with multiple choice answers.

On this form I have got a textbox that reds the question from the database and 4 radio buttons that reads the possible answers from the database. The radio buttons text names are updated with records from a database table each time the "next button" is clicked.

What I want this program to do is that when the user selects one of the radio buttons, I want the system to check if the selected radio button textname equals the right answer in the database table. for example in the table there are 5 columns namely: option1, option2, option3, option4 and rightAnswer.
So whenever a user selects a radio button, I would like the system to check if the selected radio button's textname equals the record in the "RightAnswer" column and if so I would a messagebox to show "correct" and if not the messgaebox to show "wrong"

**WORK I HAVE DONE SO FAR:**
This is the the way I am updating the radio button text names from the database.
This method is called when the form is loaded

```
void LoadingPossibleAnswers()
      {     
          Query = "SELECT * FROM AnswersTbl";
          theReader = conn.ExecuteStatement(Query);
          while (theReader.Read())
          {                      
                  radioButton1.Text = theReader["Option1"].ToString();
                  radioButton2.Text = theReader["Option2"].ToString();
                  radioButton3.Text = theReader["Option3"].ToString();
                  radioButton3.Text = theReader["Option4"].ToString();        
          }     
          conn.CloseConnection();
      }
```

This method is called when the button is clicked

```
void CorrectAnswer( RadioButton rdb)
{
    string correct = rdb.Text;

    Query = "SELECT * FROM FROM AnswersTbl;"
    theReader = conn.ExecuteStatement(Query);
    while (theReader.Read())
    {
        correct = theReader["RightAnswer"].ToString();

        if (rdb.Checked && rdb.Text == correct)
        {     
            MessageBox.Show("correct");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

When ever I run my code above, else condition executes even if the correct radio button is selected. can anyone please help to why this is? am I missing out something?

Comment: "This method is called when the button is clicked". After which button is clicked? Is it `RadioButton`?

Comment: Sorry .. that method is called when the "next button" whilst the radio button is selected.

Comment: Set a breakpoint. What might be the problem? Do the variables contain what you'd expect? Also, compare Strings via `String.Equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

As referring to your code,
do this check (`rdb.Checked`) before entering to the `CorrectAnswer` method.
Like

```
if(rdb.Checked)
{
CorrectAnswer(rdb);
}
```

Do this check for all `RadioButton`s and pass only the checked `RadioButton` to the method.

And you can remove `rdb.Checked` condition in side the `CorrectAnswer` method.